# Do I lose data if I change a text area field to Wygwam?

Tags: wygwam

I have a live site with many entries and the client would like to change the Text Areas to Wygwam fields in order to leverage the Wygwam features.

If I make this change, will I lose any existing data? Is there something I need to do to avoid losing data in the change over?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will not lose any existing data. Additionally, Wygwam gives you an option to "convert previous entries" which is very handy if your textarea field formatting was set to "Auto <br />" or "XHTML"

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alex. I appreciate the prompt (and positive) feedback.